# Integration of $f(-x)$

Tags: calculus, integration

What happens to the sign and bounds of the integral when you want to change $f(-x)$ to $f(x)$? Is the following correct? How does one convert from $xf(-x)$ to $xf(x)$?
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} xf(-x)\ dx  = -\int_{\infty}^{0} xf(x)\ dx\; ?$$

Comment: Remember what $f(-x)$ means for even vs. odd functions?

Comment: In general, that's not correct - the lower limit should become $-\infty$ when you change the variable, and the minus signs should cancel out, leaving $\int_{-\infty}^0 f(y) \, dy$.

Comment: E.g. $f(x) = x^2$.  What is $f(-x)$?  It's $f(-x) = (-x)^2 = x^2.$  So, to your question, "Is the following correct"? Not necessarily.  [Even and odd functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions)

Comment: @amWhy Are you saying that $f(x)=x^2$ is a counterexample for $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(-x)\ dx  = \int_0^{\infty} f(x)\ dx$?

Comment: No, @Pedro, read what I've said.  In fact, it's an example in which $\int_0^{\infty} f(-x) dx = \int_0^\infty f(x) \,dx$.  Whereas an odd function would mean differently.

Comment: @amWhy It seems you have said "$f(x)=x^2$ satisfies $f(-x)=f(x)$. **So**, the equality $\int_0^{\infty} f(-x) dx = \int_0^\infty f(x) \,dx$ is not necessarily correct".

Comment: That's not what I said.  I said, "So to your question, 'is the following [what the op proposes] correct?' [I answered] Not necessarily.  In fact, in the case of an **even function**", $\int_0^{\infty} f(-x) dx = \int_0^\infty f(x) \,dx$ is correct.  There you go Pedro, Akash has it correct.  Learn how to read more carefully, as well.

Comment: @amWhy It seems that your explanation makes no sense because the equality $\int_0^{\infty} f(-x) dx = \int_0^\infty f(x) \,dx$ is exactly what the OP proposed. If I am wrong, what is the incorrect assertion (originally) proposed by the OP?

Answer (score 5):

Let consider the change of variable $y=-x \implies dx=-dy$ then

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(-x)\ dx=-\int_{0}^{-\infty} f(y)\ dy=\int_{-\infty}^0 f(y)\ dy$$

Comment: What would happen if it was xf(-x) instead of just f(-x)?

Comment: @user512192 Define $g(x)=-xf(x)$. Applying the formula in the post with $f$ replaced by $g$ you get

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} xf(-x)\ dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} g(-x)\ dx=\int_{-\infty}^0 g(x)\ dx=-\int_{-\infty}^0 xf(x)\ dx$$

Comment: in this case $$\int_{0}^{\infty} xf(-x)\ dx=\int_{0}^{-\infty} yf(y)\ dy=-\int_{-\infty}^0 yf(y)\ dy$$

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x)$ is an even function then no changes will take place in the upper and lower bounds but if $f(x)$ is an odd function then you can trap the minus sign and interchange the upper and lower bounds to get the answer.

Comment: could you please explain what you mean by "trap the minus sign"?

Comment: Trapping minus sign means interchanging the lower and upper bounds of an integral.  See the process in gimusi's answer,  how he has removed the minus sign and interchanged the limits.